# Bash: variable in file path

Tags: bash, variables

I am not understanding how this doesn't work:

```
ls /sys/class/net/wlan0
addr_assign_type  broadcast  device   flags    iflink     netdev_group  queues
subsystem  uevent  addr_len carrier    dormant  ifalias  link_mode  **operstate**
speed  tx_queue_len address  dev_id  duplex   ifindex  mtu  power statistics  


for f in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do $(cat /sys/class/net/${f}/operstate); done
cat: /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/class/net/lo/operstate: No such file or directory
cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate: No such file or directory
```

I guess $f is not expanded in time for `cat`. I tried with quotes, like "$f", but still it didn't work.

This does work OK:

```
for f in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do echo /sys/class/net/${f}/operstate; done
/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
/sys/class/net/lo/operstate
/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate
```

And:

```
cat  /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate 
up
```

What have I missed? Why can't `cat` see the files in the loop?

Comment: `echo` doesn't care whether or not its argument exists in the filesystem.

Comment: Do an ls -l on /sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate

Comment: The file link to other devices (hardware names), but `cat` does work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not be repeating `/sys/class/net/` inside the loop since `$f` will already contain those directories.

```
for f in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do $(cat ${f}/operstate); done
```

Next, the `$(...)` inside the loop needs to go. There's no need to capture cat's output.

```
for f in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do cat ${f}/operstate; done
```

Now `$(ls ...)` can be done away with with a simple wildcard:

```
for f in /sys/class/net/*; do cat ${f}/operstate; done
```

Finally, the entire loop can be replaced with a single call to cat.

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/operstate
```

Comment: @Edouard I honestly don't know. Is that the exact output from your shell? Those don't look like the right error messages. I would have expected `cat: /sys/class/net//sys/class/net/eth0/operstate: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Your bash script is trying to `cat` file called `operstate` in each subdirectory of `/sys/class/net`, and the file is not found. In the second example your simply `echo`ing a string which prints out just fine.